# Navbar button won't align right when window is maximized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am building a very simple web app to help me get comfortable writing Javascript and i'm having some problems with the navbar (nothing to do with js). I have a button that I want to align right on the nav and it works fine when the window is at a small size, but when I maximize the window it no longer aligns right. The top right window is the small version of the page.

[image: the right corner window is the page]

Here is the page maximized:

[image: the maximized page]

So as you can see when the page is above a certain size the button no longer aligns. I feel this may be something obvious that I am missing (quite new to web dev here) and am wondering if there is some type of CSS class or something that I can use to make the components keep their position. e.g. `pull-right pull-right-lg`. I am using django to serve the main app page and also backbone and underscore. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'underscore-min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'backbone-min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'views.js' %}"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'App.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type='text/template' id='app_view-template'>
    <div id='app-view' class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>

            {% lorem %}
            {% lorem %}
            {% lorem %}
            {% lorem %}
            {% lorem %}
            {% lorem %}

        </div>
    </div>
</script>

    <!--HEADING AND NAVBAR-->
    <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top bg-light' 
        role='navigation'>
        <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Recipes</a>
        <div class='pull-right'>
            <ul class='nav'>
                <li>
                    <button class='btn btn-light'>
                        <span class='material-icons'>add_circle_outline</span>
                    </button>   
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!--TARGET FOR TEST VIEW-->
    <div id='app_view-target' class='container'>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using Bootstrap 4

remove the class `navbar-expand-lg`

`pull-right` is no more in BS4

> Added `.float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}` classes for responsive floats and removed `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` since they’re redundant to `.float-left` and `.float-right`.

For more information check [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/).

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks for the help. It worked. And I will be sure to read the doc at the link you gave. Thanks again.